# JSFiddle works but not on Blogger site: jQuery cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies, session-cookies, blogger, jsfiddle

As you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yjxzQ/11/ It works perfectly. If you click on the "Add to Cart" link, it shows the "Already in Cart" div and then click refresh (or run again) and it stays showing the "Already in Cart" div

Here is a link to a test post: http://sitetestexample.blogspot.com/p/add-to-cart.html As you can see, the jquery is not working at all. It's not even hiding the "Already in Cart" div on load.

The code in the post is exactly as it is in the fiddle:

```
<a href="#" id="akready-in-cart">Already in Cart</a>
<a href="#" id="add-to-cart">Add to Cart</a>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.3.1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
$('#akready-in-cart').hide();
$('#add-to-cart').click(function(){

$('#add-to-cart').hide();
$('#akready-in-cart').show();
$.cookie('akready-in-cart', true);
});

$('#akready-in-cart').click(function(){
$('#add-to-cart').show();
$('#akready-in-cart').hide();

$.cookie('akready-in-cart', false);
});
if($.cookie('akready-in-cart') == 'true'){
$('#add-to-cart').click();
} else {
$('#akready-in-cart').click();
}
</script>


<style type='text/css'>
#akready-in-cart{
margin:5px 0 0 0;
padding:3px 5px;
background:red;
color:#fff;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 24px;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about including jQuery and not just the cookie plugin, and using a document ready handler ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, in the actual post I had the plugin and the handler. Any other ideas?

Comment: Updated the post with the plugin and handler. As you can see in the test post, the jQuery plugin and handler are there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are refering to jquery.js in your code, however (from what I can tell from your test page) there is no jquery.js in your site.

Try downloading the jquery.js file and place it on your site or change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did the ladder, fix it. Thank you!